# many to many association in node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

[here is link of my code . I am getting error in index.js in api-routes-index.js. getting error undefined map function](https://github.com/tejashridbk/tejashri)

Comment: Please show piece of code where you are getting error and describe problem. so that community could help you in efficient way.

Comment: Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: [https://github.com/tejashridbk/tejashri/blob/master/api/routes/index.js] in this file i have error

Comment: You have 5 `map` usage in this file. Please, write full error (in generally you also should get in which line of code you got this error).

Answer (score 0):

I guess here you have an error:

`subcategories: products.subcategories.map(Subcategory => {`

`products` is array, you can't get `subcategories` from array. Change it to this code:

`subcategories: Product.subcategories.map(Subcategory => {`

Answer (score 0):

Many to many associations in sequilize.js
This will be helpful for you to solve the issue:

> One product has many order
>
> One order has many product
>
> As a result of many to many we have junction table "orderproduct" which contains product_id and order_id.

```
   //  In product model
    product.belongsToMany(order, {          
                through: 'orderproduct',
                foreignKey: 'product_id'
            });

   // In order model
    order.belongsToMany(product, {          
                through: 'orderproduct',
                foreignKey: 'order_id'
            });

   // In oderproduct model 
        orderproduct.belongsTo(product, {
            foreignKey: { name: 'product_id', allowNull: false }
        });
        
        orderproduct.belongsTo (order, {
            foreignKey: { name: 'order_id', allowNull: false }
        });
    }
```